# Protect JSP page from unauthorized access

Tags: jsp, security, google-signin

I have a very simple `page1.jsp` file that has a Login-with-Google button implemented. I have another `page2.jsp` file whose behavior should be:

**a)** If user has successfully logged in with Google, display the page

**b)** Otherwise, show an error message

What is the best way to implement this? I know the GateKeeper annotations in GWTP, but I cannot use them here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After successful login you must store a flag in the HttpSession object. After you can implement a filter  for control access.

Here an example: http://www.journaldev.com/1933/java-servlet-filter-example-tutorial